# Custom Exception in C# appear in throw statement . i want it to be in most outer statement which generate exception

Tags: c#, exception, runtime, throw

I am using visual studio 2013 for c# programming. I was testing for custom exception but the exception message appear in throw statement (which is correct) but I want it to appear in a line which cause exception 1st? How can I do that?

```
class Abc
{
    static void Main(String[] s)
    {
        Something(); // I want exception popup msg in this line
    }

    public static void something()
    {
        if(condition)
        {
            throw new SomeException(); // Exception popup message appear here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean to me by "i want it to appear in a line which cause exception 1st". Please try to clarify, and ideally format your code more readably next time. (Perhaps you just need a `catch` block in your `Main` method?)

Comment: You need to define this "appear" word first. I guess what you need is stack trace. - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by popup you mean the visual studio exception popup for uncaught exceptions. And you only wan't to know where something was called.
You have to check the call stack in the exception. It will tell you where something() was called.

In the exception popup click on view details to see the exception object.
In the call stack you will see something like:
SomeException thrown:
Something() in file someFile.cs 12
Main() in file someFile.cs 5

45 is the line the exception was thrown and 12 is the line something was called from.

More information on the callstack window: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx

Comment: how to do that?